# How to input current time + 12hr and 30 min through sql query as I am working with php and html on a website

Tags: php, html, linux, web, hosting

How to input **current** time + 12hr and 30 min through SQL query as I am working with php and html on a website

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT NOW() + INTERVAL 12 HOUR + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE;
```